# Grouping by a field, then counting occurrences based on the results from a separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

This is tough to explain so I'll add tables in to hopefully catch the things I don't type out well.
I have a table of products each with a country id. I want to get the count of unique products for each country id. However there are a couple tables I want to join by to determine if the sku should be counted.

I have `prods` table that looks like this
| **key_id** | **c_id** | **sku** |
|-----------|--------|-------|
| 1      | 1    | ABC |
| 2      | 2    | ABC |
| 3      | 3    | ABC |
| 4      | 1    | DEF |
| 5      | 2    | DEF |

A `filter` table (in my code it's a few inner joins of a few tables, but the goal is to make something that works like this)
| **sku** | **want_sku** |
|-------|---------------|
| ABC | 0         |
| DEF | 1         |

and this is the desired end result of my query 
| **c_id** | **# of unique_skus** |
|--------|----------------------|
| 1    | 1           |
| 2    | 1           |
| 3    | 0           |

This is what i've pieced together so far, but it's getting me the total # of skus so something is off.

```
SELECT 
  prods.c_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT prods.SKU)
FROM 
  prods
INNER JOIN
  filter
ON filter.sku = prods.sku
WHERE
  filter.want_sku = 1
GROUP BY
  prods.c_id
```

This just gets me the max # of distinct skus and assigns that to each of the different c_id. Not sure quite exactly how to fix it. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.c_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.SKU)
FROM prods p LEFT JOIN
     filter f
     ON f.sku = p.sku AND
        f.want_sku = 1
GROUP BY p.c_id;
```

Note:  I don't think you need `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, but that is how you phrased it.